# Android - Notification manager

Tags: android, notifications

I have an application in which users logged in and their details are stored in  a database.I have seen many examples of notification manager sending notifications to the same user itself.What i need now is suppose a user sent a message to his team leader,Team leader have to view this as notification in his status bar immediately after the message is sent.Thanks in Advance!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must use a push notification system, in android you can do it by using the [C2DM (Android Cloud to Device Messaging Framework)](http://code.google.com/android/c2dm/). This is the way that google chat, gmail works to deliver the notifications. Another point C2DM is only available from the API 8 (android 2.2)

Comment: Thank you... Can I do this with pull notification by polling the db with certain frequency?

Comment: You can by using the AlarmManager. But it will drain the battery of the user. for doing some prototype is ok, but for production code is better use the C2DM approach.